# como mostrar ventanas previas a MainWindow la primera vez que se abre la aplicación en WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy desarrollando un programa en WPF c# donde necesito mostrar terminos y condiciones asi como registrar datos del usuario la primera vez que este abre la app despues de instalar

MainWindow es la ventana principal pero no he encontrado la forma de determinar si es la primera vez que el usuario abre el programa, y como abrir otras ventanas antes de la ventana principal

espero alguien pueda ayudarme!!

Comment: Hola , bienvenido a [es.so]. Desafortunadamente este tipo de preguntas no son aceptadas en la comunidad, pero puedes editarla para que cumpla con los estándares de calidad establecidos. Te recomiendo que visites el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y consultes la guía [¿Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También te informo que tu pregunta puede ser cerrada, por favor, no lo tomes a mal.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción podría manejar en el AppConfig del programa una variable, en la cual verifiques sí es la primera vez que se ingresa al sistema o no, según esa variable.

**AppConfig**

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key ="firstTime" value = "1"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Ahora en tu código, harías la consulta al `key` y lo verificas y dependiendo de eso, haces lo que desees.

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[firstTime];
if (value = "1")
{
   //haces lo que ocupes


   //ahora guardas el valor nuevo diferente de 1
   string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
   string configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "App.config");
   ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
   configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;
   System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
   config.AppSettings.Settings["firstTime"].Value = "0";
   config.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[La respuesta de Randall Sandoval](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64211/38468) se puede utilizar. Pero tambien hay otras maneras de hacerlo y creo que contribuir no iria mal.

Podrias crear un archivo con un nombre en especifico y verificar si existe, sino existe entonces es porque es la primera vez que inicia y cuando haga la configuracion de inicio, creas el archivo.

```
public bool VerificarSiPrimerInicio()
{
   var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "init.app");

  return System.IO.FileExists(filePath); // si true es porque ya fue configurada
}
```

Y este metodo solo lo llamarias cuando ya fue configurada

```
public void AplicacionConfigurada()
 {
                   var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "init.app");

                  System.IO.File.Create(filePath).Close(); 

 }
```